# $\operatorname{left.fin.dim}(A)=0$ if and only if $\operatorname{soc}(A_A)$ contains an isomorphic copy of every simple right $A$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

I've been trying to find an (easy) example to show that there exists an Artin algebra $A$ such that $\operatorname{right.fin.dim}(A)\neq\operatorname{left.fin.dim}(A)$, where $\operatorname{left.fin.dim}(A)$ (respectively **right**) is the supremum of the projective dimensions of all finitely generated left (**right**) $A$-modules that have finite projective dimension.

By "easy" I mean as elementary as possible, particularly something that doesn't use Auslander-Reiten quivers.

With that aim, I found in the notes "Finitistic dimensions of monomial algebras" by Simon Rubinstein-Salzedo the following statement (he quotes it as "Auxiliary fact 2" and makes a reference to Bass'article "Finitistic dimension and a homological generalization of semi-primary rings"):

$\operatorname{left.fin.dim}(A)=0$ if and only if $\operatorname{soc}(A_A)$ contains an isomorphic copy of every simple right $A$-module.

Try as I may, I can't find the proof of that statement in Bass's article. Could someone provide a proof of the fact? (a more specific reference would be enough).

Answer (score 1):

This is Lemma 6.2 in Bass's article.

The condition he actually states is that every simple left module is a quotient of an injective module. But for Artin algebras, finitely generated injective left modules are dual to finitely generated projective right modules, so by duality it's equivalent to the condition that Rubinstein-Salzedo quotes.

Comment: But that lemma talks about the $\operatorname{Fin.dim}$, which is not the same as the $\operatorname{fin.dim}$ since it also considers modules that are not finitely generated.

Comment: @Maru For Artin algebras (or more generally perfect rings) Fin.dim.=0 if and only if fin.dim.=0. See Theorem 6.3 in Bass's article.

Comment: @Maru Alternatively, for an Artin algebra I think the proof of Bass's Lemma 6.2 still works if you add the condition that every module mentioned is finitely generated.

Comment: Yes, I believe so too; once you pointed me in that direction that is exactly what I did. However, I'm still stuck with the socle condition... Once I dualize the result in the lemma I suppose I get a monomorphism from my simple left module to a projective module. How does this relate to $\operatorname{soc}(A)$?

Comment: @Maru Every projective right module is a direct summand of a free module, so if a simple module embeds in any projective module then it is isomorphic to a (simple) submodule of a free module and hence of $\operatorname{soc}(A)$.